# Set attribute on <a>, not <li>

Tags: jquery, attr

I have

```js
lnk = $("<a>" + appendopts.text + "</a>")
                .attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));
```

I need

```html
<li><a href=""></a></li>
```

I tried

```js
lnk = $("<li><a>" + appendopts.text + "</a></li>")
                .attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));
```

I get the wrong output. What do I have to do? How do I add the `attr` to the `a` element and not to the `li` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : create anchor tag first and then append it to `li`

```
var lnk = $("<a>" + appendopts.text + "</a>")
                .attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));

var li = $('<li></li>').append(lnk);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listItem = $("<li><a href='" + this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id) + "'>" + appendopts.text + "</a></li>");
```

The other two answers are fine, just thought it was worth posting an alternative.

Basically, just a big concatenated string.

Answer (score -1):

`attr()` (and other methods) will always apply to the outermost element in your selector.

You'll need to handle them separately:

```
var a = $("<a>" + appendopts.text + "</a>").
  attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));

lnk = $('<li>').
  append(a);
```

Comment: This solution works for OP and still -1 vote. I don't understand how can people downvote without verifying the solution provided.